# show the meta values to visitors that collected via coment form

Tags: customization, comments, comment-meta

in stackoverflow ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4054943/customize-wordpress-comment-post-query/)) there is a solution for collecting extra information from visitors, and i want to ask that, is it possible to show the collected information to other visitors in his/her comment section?
Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the link you have provided it shows how to get the value of the "collected" meta using

```
$twitter = get_comment_meta($comment_ID,'_twitter',true);
```

so all that is left for you to do is edit your comments loop and add the next few lines in it.

```
$extra_field = get_comment_meta($comment_ID,'_extra_field',true);
echo $extra_field;
```

Hope this Helps